# the disadvantage of using 2d arrays instead of pointers in a programming languages?

Tags: arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, linked-list

*(this is a general question I am not referring it to a specific language as almost all languages use pointers)*

I have been looking around a lot but I cannot see why **using 2D arrays cannot replace pointers.**

For example if a program do not have a pointer why is it **dangerous** to use **2D arrays**... what is the **actual difference between 2D Arrays and Pointers**.

If 2D arrays will do the job what is the need of pointers?

For Example if we use **two arrays** then **an integer** to keep **record for the  how many record have been used**

I want to know what kind of **problems** I (programmers) may face if I use **2D Arrays** instead of **pointer**?

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gTOJH0E.jpg

Comment: Do you work in a market? @ergonaut

Comment: You can think of an array as a preallocated set of pointers, like an empty egg carton that lets you put eggs in it.  Generic 'pointers' are like your index fingers, which can move around wherever they want to point to any egg.  They are different things.  You'll have to give a specific example of how you would use "either 2D arrays OR pointers".

Comment: Do you perceive and advantage to using 2D arrays over pointers? Tell us why it would be beneficial.

Comment: Values[100], where "Value" is a real. (Values[i] holds the [i]th value)
Next [100], where "Next" is an integer.(Next[i] gives the index of the next record)
Last, which is an integer. (Counts how many record have been used) @ergonaut

Answer (score 0):

In languages that *don't have* pointers (e.g. older versions of FORTRAN), programmers will often use arrays to build more-complex data structures. This is a technique of last-resort in most cases, because the pointer notation is more natural, and so avoids a lot of cognitive load, where you have to keep track of multiple arrays, multiple index variables, and the like, just to implement a simple list or tree structure.

In C and many related languages, arrays are a fixed size, set at initialization, which means that if you want to have a data structure that can become arbitrarily-large, you pretty much *have to* use pointers. On the other hand, if you know that a particular data set actually has a fixed size, then using an array to represent it can actually be somewhat more-efficient than the equivalent pointer-based structure.